# Number of ways to obtain n as sum of 1,...,m

Tags: combinatorics, integers

Let $m \leq n $. I want to find the number of ways $N$ in which $n$ can be written as a sum of elements in $\{1,\ldots, m\} $, with repetitions. For example, if $n=5$ and $m=3$, then $N=13$, because  $\{1,1,1,1,1\}, \{2,1,1,1\}, \{1,2,1,1\} \ldots \{2,2,1\}, \{2,1,2\}, \{1,2,2\}, \{3,2\}, \{2,3\}$ all sum to 5. What about $m>2$? Is it possible to find a general solution?

Comment: It might be worth approaching via generating functions.  Consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x^1+x^2+\dots+x^m)^i$.

Comment: Generating functions are your friends :)

$f(x)=(1+x+x^2+...+x^m)^n$, then what you want is $[x^n]f(x)$

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) and [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf) more information.

Comment: @Masacroso also, your generating function is slightly off, as it would consider $\{2,0,2,0,1\}$ to be different than $\{2,0,0,2,1\}$.  I would consider these to both be the same, i.e $\{2,2,1\}$.

Comment: I see @JMoravitz. Yes, I dont check too much the function, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N_m(n)$ denote the function you're interested in, i.e., the number of ways to write $n$ as an ordered sum of positive integers less than or equal to $m$.  Once you have values for $N_m(0),N_m(1),\ldots,N_m(m-1)$, the rest satisfy the recursion

$$N_m(n)=N_m(n-1)+N_m(n-2)+\cdots+N_m(n-m)$$

That's because the first number in an ordered sum for $n\ge m$ can be any number up to $m$.

In particular, for $m=2$, you get the Fibonacci numbers (not the identity function $N=n$).

Comment: You're right, I corrected my error.